# Searching a string in a directory and all of its subdirectories using C

Tags: c, string, file, directory

I am trying to find the occurrences of a string in a directory and written the code below.
I am getting a return value of 3221225725 and a blank output.
The folder is located in the same folder as my main.c file maybe the issue is that but i'll appreciate if you looked at my code too.
P.S this code is a test sample that looks at one directory and a .txt file in it

```c
#include <dirent.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent dirp;
    searchDirectoryForString("testdir", "Mathematics");
    return 0;
}

const char *getFileExtension(const char *filename)
{
    const char *dot = strrchr(filename, '.');
    if (!dot || dot == filename)
        return "";
    return dot + 1;
}
void searchDirectoryForString(char *dname, char *str)
{
    int lineno = 1, resultoccr = 0;
    DIR *dp;
    FILE *fp;
    struct dirent *file;
    char temp[2048];

    dp = opendir(dname);
    struct stat filestat;

    while ((file = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    {
        stat(file->d_name, &filestat);
        if (S_ISDIR(filestat.st_mode))
        {
            searchDirectoryForString(file->d_name, str);
        }
        else if (S_ISREG(filestat.st_mode))
        {
            fp = fopen(file->d_name, "r");
            if (getFileExtension(file->d_name) == "txt")
            {
                // file search
                while (fgets(temp, 2048, fp) != NULL)
                {
                    if ((strstr(temp, str)) != NULL)
                    {
                        printf("target at line: %d\t", lineno);
                        printf("%s\n", temp);
                        resultoccr++;
                    }
                    lineno++;
                }
            }
        }
        close(fp);
    }
    if (resultoccr == 0)
    {
        printf("\n target is not in file\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `main.c:36:48: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress] if (getFileExtension(file->d_name) == "txt")`. Might be this

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your code with `gcc` use extra warning flags to spot possible mistakes easier.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic main.c
```

The output of the command above will give some warning. One of the warnings is relevant for this issue:

```
main.c: In function ‘searchDirectoryForString’:
main.c:36:48: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
   36 |             if (getFileExtension(file->d_name) == "txt")
      |                                                ^~
```

`getFileExtension()` returns a pointer inside the `file->d_name` variable. Remember that a pointer is an address. You are comparing an address inside `file->d_name` and a constant pointer to character array  `"txt"`. What you want is to compare character values one by one until the end of string. Try something like this:

```c
if (strncmp(getFileExtension(file->d_name),"txt", 3) == 0)
{
...
```

Edit (extra bugs I've found):

bug 1:
Your program will eventually crash because one of the directories returned from `readdir()` is `.` (current directory). This will lead to infinite loop with following arguments: `searchFirectoryForString(".", "Mathematics")`. You need to add an exclusion for current directory `.` and parent directory `..` like so:

```c
while ((file = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    {
        stat(file->d_name, &filestat);
        if (S_ISDIR(filestat.st_mode))
        {
            if(strncmp(file->d_name, ".", 1) == 0){
                break;
            }
            if(strncmp(file->d_name, "..", 2) == 0){
                break;
            }
            searchDirectoryForString(file->d_name, str);
        }
     ...
```

bug 2:
You'll have to fix some some logical errors when you check what kind of file you get returned (directory or regular file). I suggest you check out documentation for `readdir` (in terminal run `man readdir`). They have an example using a switch case.

bug 3:
When opening nested directories make sure you pass in relative path to that file. Assume directory structure like below:

```
.
├── a.out
├── main.c
└── testdir
    └── rand_file.txt
```

your program will find `rand_file.txt` and try to open it by invoking `fopen("rand_file.txt", "r")` instead of `fopen("testdir/rand_file.txt", "r")`.

Comment: I've tried to  use `char rpath[200]= "\\testdir\\" `(im on Windows 10)  then use strcat to add the file name to get the relative path but im now getting a blank input with a return value of 0. And the message for the case of the string not being in the file doesnt work either.


     `strcat(rpath, file->d_name); fp=fopen(rpath,"r");`

Comment: in your program you're assuming that libc functions always returns what you want. You need to check the return value on each call to stdlib and make sure those functions are returning the value you expect. libc functions set a global error number defined in errno.h you can use that to see what the issue is.

Comment: I have tried using errno.h but my program doesnt return an error number either. I had the program print the error number if the file pointer was null. It doesnt print anything. Just a blank output.

Comment: then, most likely the error occurred earlier. `errno` is unset once a new call is being made. Put asserts and `errno` after each syscall